# Convert Parse "Number" field to integer?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I am retrieving a Parse object like so:

```
  PFObject *countObject=[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"count"];
```

count is "5" (set on the control panel on Parse.com). How do I convert this object into an int? want to do

```
 int x = countObject;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the value returned by

```
[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"count"];
```

is a NSNumber, so you can use intValue method [NSNumber reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html)

```
id num = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"count"]
int x =  [num intValue];
```

If you have a doubt on the returned value you can use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"count"] class]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
int x =[countObject integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

With checking of the kind of class to avoid future problems.

```
Class numberClass = [NSNumber class];
id countObject = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:METagCount];
if ([countObject isKindOfClass:numberClass])
{
   NSNumber *count = (NSNumber *) countObject;
   int x = filesize.integerValue;
}
```